# Trying to deploy puppeteer on vercel using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, puppeteer, vercel

I am trying to deploy my script on vercel using nodejs.

node v - 18x
ppuppeteer v - 21.7.0
**Could not find Chrome (ver. 119.0.6045.105)**

when I try to execute the script it gives me an error :

```
Error: Could not find Chrome (ver. 119.0.6045.105). This can occur if either
 1. you did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. `npx puppeteer browsers install chrome`) or
 2. your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: /home/sbx_user1051/.cache/puppeteer).
For (2), check out our guide on configuring puppeteer at https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration.
    at ChromeLauncher.resolveExecutablePath (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ProductLauncher.js:278:27)
    at ChromeLauncher.executablePath (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:209:25)
    at ChromeLauncher.computeLaunchArguments (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:103:37)
    at async ChromeLauncher.launch (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ProductLauncher.js:69:28)
    at async way_bill_generate (/var/task/controller/orders/orders.js:784:21)
```

code :

```
   options = {
      headless: true,
      // executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser',
      args: [
        "--no-sandbox",
        "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
        "--disable-web-security",
        "--hide-scrollbars",
        "--font-render-hinting=none",
      ],
    }

const browser = await puppeteer.launch(options);

const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setContent(html)

await page.emulateMediaType("screen");
    await page.setViewport({
      width: 1200,
      height: 800,
    });


    const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf({
      margin: { top: "50px", right: "50px", bottom: "50px", left: "50px" },
      printBackground: true,
      preferCSSPageSize: true,
      format: "A4",
    });

    await browser.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After so many research I got the solution. If you want to use Puppeteer with serverless architecture I found this [official git repo](https://github.com/Sparticuz/chromium?tab=readme-ov-file) . This is only
supported specified version of chromium with particular puppeteer version. To check check which version you should use [support check](https://pptr.dev/chromium-support) .

or if **Migration from chrome-aws-lambda**

```
const chromium = require("@sparticuz/chromium");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-core");

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  let result = null;
  let browser = null;

  try {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      args: chromium.args,
      defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
      executablePath: await chromium.executablePath(),
      headless: chromium.headless,
      ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    });

    let page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto(event.url || 'https://example.com');

    result = await page.title();
  } catch (error) {
    return callback(error);
  } finally {
    if (browser !== null) {
      await browser.close();
    }
  }

  return callback(null, result);
};
```